# BasicTextField doesn't move up title on focus

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

Hi this is my BasicTextField :

```
fun TextFieldRow(data: TextFieldData) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val text by data.text.observeAsState("")
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 17.dp)
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                data.text.value = it
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 6.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .indicatorLine(
                    enabled = true,
                    isError = false,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors()
                )
        ) { innerTextField ->
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = text,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                enabled = true,
                singleLine = true,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithLabelPadding(start = 4.dp),
                label = { Text(text = data.label) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I set the label in the TextFieldDecorationBox. It work well when I type some letters (the title goes up), but when I just take focus, the title stay in the middle. Any help ?

**EDIT**
I would like something like that, the reason why I use BasicTextField instead of TextField is because I want to manage padding.

[image: Material io example]

Answer (score 0):

You can change innerTextField like;

```
BasicTextField(
  //
){ innerTextField ->
   Box{
      if(text.value.isEmpty())
         Text(
            text = "Title",
            color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
         )
      innerTextField()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i edit my question, your solution is for a placeholder and not a label.